# Modeling a pillow with borders

Tags: cloth-simulation

I would like to model a pillow with the borders, like this:

[image]

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

**Update:**
This is where I got to:
[image]

I would like more definition to the seams, and also less rounded format.

I followed the steps:

1. Added a plane and added thickness
2. Selected the center polygons and included in a vertex group 'pressure'
3. Selected the vertices around the center polygons and named it 'sewing'
4. On cloth, I applied 15 pressure to the center polygons, and added the pressure vertex to the pin group.

It looks good for me, but I wish it could be more realistic like the image I provided.

Comment: What have you tried as far and which part of that are you struggling with?

Comment: I have: set a vertex group for the pressure part, and set a pin group for the part that separate the pressure from non pressure, it looks average, would love to know more solutions.

Comment: It's not really super clear from the description alone. Could you edit the question and add a few screenshots of what you have maybe?

Comment: What means *"it looks average"*? Don't be shy and add a screenshot. (*Screenshot! Screeenshot! Screeenshot!!!*). How else should I know if my solution might be better than yours?

Comment: Hello, I just updated it! Thank you so much

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the update. I think there is a small mistake. About 4., the *Pin* group is the *sewing* vertex group, not the *pressure* group, right? Have you allowed some growing (negative *Shrink* value) and have you used *Self Collision*? I've tried to follow your steps but without a about -0.125 Shrink value the result is very rigid. It looks like a a picture frame and a canvas that wants to come out. It doesn't look like a pillow at all. Your result looks great. For more realism, I would add more prominent seams (test example: https://imgur.com/a/poEGmNw)